# angular-chart.js - x-axis doesn't align when one result only is shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js to display a graph, using the following snippet:

```
 <center ng-hide="{{noStats}}" class="col-md-8">
                <canvas class="col-lg-8 chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
                    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick" ng-cloak>
                </canvas>
                <h1 ng-show="{{noStats}}"> No stats available for selected range. </h1>
 </center>
```

When only one point is show on the graph like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5KJc.png),

[image]

the x-axis value is not aligned under the point but appears on the very left of the axis. The documentation of angular-chart.js is not very thorough, so how can I fix it?